# Inconsistent average results for while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program takes input from the user, counts the number of letters in the string, adds them to a variable and then divides the total of that variable by the number of words entered to get the average. I'm finding that I'm getting inconsistent results for my averages. What am I doing wrong?

```
word_length_count = 0
count = 0
average = 0

word = input("Enter a word (press Enter to quit): ")
count = count + 1
word_length_count = round(word_length_count + len(word))
average = len(word)
while count == 1:
    word = input("Enter a word (press Enter to quit): ")
    if word == "":
        break
    else:
        while word != "":
            word = input("Enter a word (press Enter to quit): ")
            count = count + 1
            word_length_count = round(word_length_count + len(word))
            average = round(word_length_count / count)

print("The average length of the words entered is", round(average))
```

Comment: Unrelated to the average bug, but you have three different places you are asking for input and doing identical calculations.  If you *greatly* simplify this to ask / compute in a single place, I'm sure you'll see the error immediately.

Comment: This was to ensure that the program would run even if the user only entered a single word

Comment: What do you mean by "inconsistent"? Please give a clear [mre]. For example, do you get a different result **for the same input**, if you try the program **starting over from the beginning** twice? If not, then what exactly is the inconsistency? Show a simple example of what input you provide to the program, step by step what you think should happen for that input (and why), and step by step what appears to happen instead (and how that is different).

Comment: I recommend taking one of hundreds of online Python classes, many free, or picking up a book. Stackoverflow isn't intended for tutelage from scratch, which, based on your questions history, is what you will benefit from.

Answer (score -2):

There's no point to `round()` integer values (and string length cannot be fractional). There's no much point of nested loop here as it serves no purpose and all can be handled in one. Not to mention use of `else` can be removed as this is simple logic and if condition is met then script loop terminates so no point:

```py
word_length_count = 0
count = 0


while True:
    word_len = len(input("Enter a word (press Enter to quit): "))
    if word_len == 0:
       break
    count += 1
    word_length_count += word_len

if count > 0:
    average = word_length_count / count
    print(f"The average length of the {count} words entered is {average:.2f}")
else:
    print("No words were entered.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't quite understand what is happening here (average:.2f)
I'm guessing the second f is unrelated to a formatted string. No idea about the :.2

Comment: That string is so called [fstring](https://fstring.help/cheat/) that that particular syntax tell python you want value of `average` to be put there, with specific formatting. In this case it should be using `average` as *f*loat, and display with two digits in decimal part (that's why 2 is after dot). see https://fstring.help/cheat/ or python docs for more